# Android Full Screen Keyboard for TextField inside a webview

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

Usually in landscape mode an EditText will open the IME in full screen mode, but for an textfield inside a webview (loaded as a HTML content) it doesn't and it pushes the existing view upwards.

I tried something like this but it has the same behaviour:

```
public void onUserInteraction(){
    super.onUserInteraction();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webview.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

i need something like this:

[image]

opera mobile web browser is doing it great. but for the default browser of android and webview it is not. is there any way? thanks for any help!